# How to create a pop-out button in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, user-interface, vue-component, popupwindow

I am starting to develop a Vue.js based application that is replacing a desktop application. What customer is asking is the option to be able to pop-out different parts of the application (to be able to put it in the another window)
The idea is like in email applications, like GMail.com, you can click on pop-out in the middle of the work and you can continue your work in the new window.
I was wondering if there is an efficient and clean way to do this?

Comment: It totally depends on the definition of 'window'. Real browser window and modal window are totally different things.

Comment: I meant real browser window. The problem with modal is they can't be moved to another monitor. The idea is the customer opens and views two or three window of our Vue.js application (different sections) at the same time.

Comment: There should be different Vue sub-apps for that. You're limited to interacting with localStorage events (same origin only), postMessage or websocket server between apps.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask , can you guide me to more information on sub-app please?

Comment: There should be different Vue apps, they can have common components but with entry points most likely need to be different because popup layout is different and doesn't have all the functionality of main app. See `pages` option if you use Vue CLI.